# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions of UIsegmented button

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uigraphicscontext

I have a screen with Text, labels and Uisegmented button.
I want to take a complete snapshot of the screen and save as a image.

This is the code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage*theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData*theImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1.0 ); //you can use PNG too
[theImageData writeToFile:@"example.jpeg" atomically:YES];
```

But the option which is selected in Uisegmented button appears filled opaque. I have changed the second parameter in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to false. Stiil i see it filled. Is there anything i am missing?

Here is the image.[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`?

Comment: @matt : I am using this for the first time. Can you help me with some links or examples.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems specific to the `UISegmentedControl` class. I don't know why it is happening, but something like below should do the trick.

```
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor orangeColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Maybe this information would be helpful for further investigation of the problem for you.